# Ubuntu half screen frozen

Tags: mouse-scroll

I have installed ubuntu 22.04 for Linux. Initially, it was working well but today when I opened the system, the right portion of the screen was black. When I open the applications tab. It is all visible. There is no black area. But there, the remaining left portion of the screen that was visible on desktop, does not allow the mouse to click. I can move the cursor over there but cant click. And the right portion is working well on it.